# show label in current index in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a button labeled save.
I want it to show when someone changes its corresponding textbox value. How to do this in angularjs.
but now when 
I click changes something in textbox all the buttons in ng-repeat will active at the same time

```js
increaseQty:function(){
  qty++;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="test in tests">
  <label>{{test.price}}</label>
  <label>{{text.qty}}</label>
  <button>increase qty</button>
</div>
```

but the problem is all product qty get updated.

Comment: you should post the code you are trying. and you can use ng-change

Comment: post edited kindly check

Comment: that is your complete code? you have only one button and from where your are changing value I dont see any text box.

Comment: okk just replace the textbox with label

Answer (score 0):

You explained two different scenarios in your question. Anyways i will try to answer related to the code you added.
You basically need to pass record for which you need to update your quantity like below.

```
  $scope.increaseQty = function(item){
  item.qty++;
 }
```

Check out below js fiddle link formore clarity on this.

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/anilsarkar/gj2c9n0h/29/

Answer (score 0):

This will show a button when corresponding price or qty has changed.

```js
increaseQty:function(){
  qty++;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="test in tests">
  <label ng-change="test.haschange=true">{{test.price}}</label>
  <label ng-change="test.haschange=true" >{{text.qty}}</label>
  <button ng-if="test.haschange" >increase qty</button>
</div>
```